# How to get input value using class in prototype?

Tags: javascript, input, prototypejs

I did try but something is wrong I don't know what?
I'm trying to get value from input using a class

```
   <script>
function showResult()
{
 var val = $$(".qty")[0];
 var val2 = val.innerHTML;   
  alert("Hey " +val2 );
}
</script>
<input class='qty' value="3"><br />
<input class='qty2' value="3">
<input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="showResult();"/>
```

[There is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/u4U8E/4/)
I can get this value if I use div but for input doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `var val2 = val.innerHTML;` to

```
var val2 = val.value;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u4U8E/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

```
var value = $$(".qty")[0].value;
alert("Hey " + value);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using `jQuery`, right?  If so, try this:

```
<script>

    function showResult(){
        var val=$(".qty").val();
        alert("Hey "+val);
    }

    function showTheSameResult(val){
        alert("Hey "+val);
    }
</script>
```

On the page:

```
<div class="qty" onclick="showTheSameResult(value);">
    <!--- stuff  -->
</div>
```